# Need help on SQL Query with 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Currently I have the following 4 tables: customer, customer_orders_product, customer_order and customer

[image]

What I am trying to do is to run a query that could show the following columns:

order_id, product_name, quantity and order total (which is quantity * 
product_price)

But I am not sure if there is any query that is capable to do so, any help on this?
Furthermore, is there any query with JOIN syntax that I could run with those 4 tables?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The query by Mureinik works flawlessly. I was confused and did not know how to use the JOIN query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just join each pair of tables according to the fields that reference each other:

```
SELECT co.order_id, 
       p.product_name, 
       cop.quantity, 
       cop.quantity * p.product_price AS total
FROM   customer_order co
JOIN   customer_order_product cop ON co.order_id = cop.order_id
JOIN   product p ON cop.product_id = p.product_id
```

Incidentally, you don't need all four tables for this query - the customer details are irrelevant for your question.

Comment: @Fuji, additionally, if you wanted the customer's name, in your result set, you could add another join based on the customer_order.customer_ID to the customer.customer_ID

Comment: @DRapp Thanks for your advice, it works great as you said.